# Footer Covering Site Elements

Tags: html, css

I recently redesigned [my website](http://www.halenmartini.ga) and this is my first experience using the header and footer elements. On some pages, the footer will cover elements. What are some decent solutions for this? [Example at the bottom of the midi page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei5P9.png)

Footer HTML code:

```
<footer style="position: fixed;">
    <a href="index.html">Back</a>
</footer>
```

Footer CSS:

```
footer {
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #000099;
  padding: 10px;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Thanks, Halen. (this is my first time using stack overflow to ask a question, so if I get something wrong please don't hit me lol)

Comment: When you have `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`, the element "looses" it's size (width, height). So the browser thinks your footer is of no size, when it comes in comparison to other elements on the page. I like Ishiaq's solution by adding a `margin-margin` to body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add style for the last element in your page like this; `style="margin-bottom: 50px;"` For example for your **midi.html** page.

```
<audio controls="" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
```

Your browser does not support the audio tag.
`

**OR** You can also solve this problem by adding `margin-bottom: 50px;` with the `body`.i.e.

```
body {
background-color: #1d41e2;
text-align: center;
font-family: "Helvetica";
margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome.
you can add this:

```
margin-bottom: 60px;
```

to the last `<audio>` element,

**or:**
warp all the content between `<header>` and `<footer>` inside `<div>` and style it as above.